# Postgres query to find a specific element within a group of values

Tags: postgresql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table `box` with the following entries:

```
 eventid | uuid | rack           
---------+------+----
0        | 0    | r1
1        | 1    | r2
2        | 0    | r2
```

where the uuid is constant and every update which happens to a specific box a new event is added with a new event id but the uuid remains.

What I am trying to do is figure out a way to get the latest edition of a box based upon specific rack.

When I search for rack r2 I want eventid 2 and 1, and when I search for rack r1 I want to find nothing.

So far I have this query:

```
select distinct on (uuid) * 
from dbo.box as t 
where t ==> 'r2' 
order by t.uuid, t.eventid DESC;
```

Which returns the correct data for r2 however if I use this query with r1 I get eventId 0 when I want nothing.

I am assuming you need to do some sort of sub-query for this to get all the latest editions of the uuids based on the event id and then do the where clause but I am not very well versed in postgres, so if anyone could assist I would be most appreciative.

Comment: What is `where t ==> 'r2'` supposed to do? `==>` not a standard Postgres operator

Comment: It is not clear to me why you don't want to find nothing for r1 although there is a data set... What means "latest edition"?

Comment: Why do you expect nothing for rack r1? Shouldn't that return eventid 0?

Comment: the ==> is a postgres extension operator (zombodb) which connects elasticsearch with postgres. I expect nothing in rack r1 because the uuid is no longer in rack r1, it has been moved to r2 therefore when searching in r1 you should find nothing as it has been moved. its event based so each event that happens is a new entry in the db so its there for history purposes but should not actually be searchable unless explicitly stated.

Comment: So what happens if an r3 is added?  Will the uuid column for all r2s be set to 0?

Comment: no if an entirely new entry is added with shelf = r3 then that entry will be got if you search "r3" but everything else stays the same. If you update 1 element from r2 to r3 then you should only get the one you didnt update when you search for r2. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't have your extension operator (==> now do I necessary understand it's operation). So I cannot test the following, but it might be worth a try. You can add a NOT EXISTS predicate to the where clause.

```
select distinct on (uuid) * 
from dbo.box as t 
where t ==> 'r2' 
  and not exists
      (select null
         from dbo.box nt
        where nt.uuid = t.uuid
          and nt.eventid > t.eventid
      )
order by t.uuid, t.eventid DESC;
```

As far as your comment I'm not sure it does make any sense.